# iOS - Rotating objects using core animation and longpress UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, core-graphics, core-animation

So, I created a simple app when the user press a long press on the button it rotates the `CALayer`, and when the user remove his hands from the button the `CALayer` speed is set to `0` so the `CALayer` stops on the last point and then complete from the same point.

(SOLVED) My first problem is, it takes time to make the button do the action of the long press. "Solved using `UIControlEventTouchDown` "

My second problem is, I want the `CALayer` to stop rotating on a specific angle.

My third problem is, I want to make two `UIButton`s one for rotating left and the another for rotating to the right side.

Here's my code:

```
@interface anApp ()
{
CALayer *lyr;
}

@end
-(void)viewDidLoad{
//The layer
lyr.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 190);
lyr.position = CGPointMake(90, 190);
lyr.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[self.view.layer addSubLayer:lyr];
//The rotate animation
CABasicAnimation *anima = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
anima.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:9];
anima.removedOnCompletion = NO;
anima.repeatCount= HUGE_VAL;
anima.duration = 1.1f;
[lyr addAnimation:anima forKey:@"rota"];
//Set speed to zero
lyr.timeOffset = [lyr convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
lyr.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
lyr.speed = 0.0;

//Long press UIButton
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theHeight/2, theWidth);
btn.center = CGPointMake(theHeight/1.33, theWidth/2);
[self.view addSubview:btn];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
[btn addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}

//The long press UIButton action
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
//if the user pressed a long press on a button
if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
//set the speed to 1
lyr.speed = 1.0;
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = lyr.timeOffset;
lyr.timeOffset = 0.0;
lyr.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [lyr convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
lyr.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}

//if the user removed his/her finger from the button
if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
//set the speed of the layer to 0
lyr.timeOffset = [lyr convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
lyr.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
lyr.speed = 0.0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first problem, I don't think you understand "long press". Of course it takes time to start. It's by design. You don't want to use that. Take a look at the touch down, and touch up actions. Look in the Apple docs, or find some tutorials. I think you are needing a better understanding of the basics.

I think you should fix that first, then see if you can figure out how to solve your third problem more easily once you are using the correct event code.

As to your second problem, I really don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. What angle? Are you trying to snap to 90/180/270/0 degrees? Please provide info.

Comment: The second problem I mean to stop rotating the layer when its on 130 degrees. Thanks for help